# Как сделать переключение между персонажами в unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку персонажи переключались между собой. Но у меня возник баг, персонаж 2 не появляется на месте персонажа 1, а на своём изначальном месте.

Вот код переключателя, который прикреплён к Players, а char1 и char2 являются дочерними:

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

public class Switcer : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject char1, char2;

int charOn = 1;

void Start()
{

char1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
char2.gameObject.SetActive(false);

}

public void SwitchCharecter()
{

   switch (charOn)
   {

        case 1:
        charOn = 2;

        char1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        char2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        break;
        case 2:
        charOn = 1;
        char1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        char2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        break;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Почему баг? В коде не видно, что бы менялись позиции объектов после активации. Значит не баг, а невнимательность.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (charOn)
   {

        case 1:
        charOn = 2;

        char1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        char2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        char2.transform.position = char1.transform.position;
        break;
        case 2:
        charOn = 1;
        char1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        char2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        char1.transform.position = char2.transform.position;
        break;
       }
   }
```